# local RTP port unreachable when using mjsip/jmf

Tags: sip, jmf, nat, rtp, mjsip

I create a sip session with mjsip to an external voip provider. Then I transmit a test wav file over rtp to the provider using RtpManager.

The program runs with no errors and I answer the sip call. However, no audio is transmitted. When I diagnose the network traffic with wireshark, I see a bunch of RTP traffic from my localhost (behind some kind of nat) to the voip provider and nothing back.

After a while I get the ICMP error "Destination unreachable (Port unreachable)" from the provider to my localhost.

The software linphone works using the same localhost and voip provider - though it is using a different sip stack.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm really interrested in your project. Can you tell me how you did the call with mjsip? How do you stream the test wav file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already answered your own question, but yes, you're right: The Callee/UAS will, after some period of time, regard the connection as having failed to be established if it hasn't received an ACK.

The [SIP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-17.2) tells us that the UAS's server INVITE transaction will enter the Completed state when it sends a 200 OK. Receipt of an ACK sends it to the Confirmed state.

If, however, the UAS either has a transport error when sending the 200 OK or fails to timeously receive an ACK (Timer H fires (64*T1 = 64*500m = 32 seconds by default), the UAS will move to the Terminated state.

Answer (score 2):

D'oh!

The issue was found to be that I did not send an ACK to a SIP 200 message when my call was accepted in my call listener class. So the voip client ignored the corresponding rtp requests.

```
public void onCallAccepted(Call call, String sdp, Message resp){
    System.out.println("call accepted");
    call.ackWithAnswer(sdp); //this was the missing line I needed
    this.setupRtpSession(call);
}
```

Hopefully this helps anyone with a similar problem